# Install Browsersync Gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-browser-sync

When I tried to install Browsersync by this way:

```
npm -i browser-sync --save-dev
```

I get some errors:

> D:\projekt>npm install --save-dev browser-sync
>
> npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.7: use uuid module instead
>   projekt@1.0.0 D:\projekt
>   `-- browser-sync@2.18.7
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
>   npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> npm WARN projekt@1.0.0 No repository field.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

They are only warnings:

> npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.7: use uuid module instead projekt@1.0.0 D:\projekt `-- browser-sync@2.18.7

A deprecated module which is used by Browsersync.

---

> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

You are using Windows operating system instead of OSX, and it does not support `fsevents` package.

---

> npm WARN projekt@1.0.0 No repository field.

You have not yet set Git repository URL of your project in `package.json` file. For example:

```
{
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/user/project"
  }
}
```

Comment: how can I fix it ?

Comment: As I said, they are all warnings, not errors, you can leave them as they are and they do not affect your project. The first one depends on the developers of Browsersync. The second one, use MacOS (Apple computer). The third one if you host your project on a repository hosting service (GitHub, BitBucket), copy the hyperlink to `package.json` as above.